# Как зарегистрировать конструктор класса C# в Lua

Tags: c#, lua

Использую C# класс:

```
public class TestClass
    {
        int _a;
        public void Set(int a)
        {
            _a = a;
        }
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_a);
        }
    }
```

Регистрирую его:

```
Lua lua = new Lua();
lua["Debug"] = new TestClass();
lua.DoFile("script.lua");
```

И вызываю его из скрипта:

```
a=Debug
a:Set(5)
a:Print()
```

Что мне надо добавить или изменить, чтобы использовать конструктор с параметрами?

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на enSO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/44100984/5472058

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо сначала импортировать соответствующее пространство имён, в котором находится ваш класс `TestClass` для его использования в lua-скрипте:

```
namespace Application
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        int _a;

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_a);
        }

        public TestClass(int a)
        {
            this._a = a;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Lua lua = new Lua();
lua.LoadCLRPackage();
lua.DoFile("script.lua");
```

Код файла script.lua:

```
import ('Application')
a=TestClass(5)
a:Print()
```

Источник: [мой ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102002/5472058)